# Drush 8.0.3 is unable to update D7 modules

Tags: drush

I have Drush installed via Homebrew on my Mac. I am currently unable to execute "drush up" in a Drupal web site. When I attempt, I get the error:

Destination directory [...] already exists.

Is this normal? Do I need to use a different version? Do I need to stop using Homebrew?

Comment: what does `drush up -debug` tell you? I'd imagine if Drush 8 was _completely_ broken that thousands of complaints would be filed, so it's probably an issue with your local system; such as Permissions, PHP, etc.

Comment: As far as I can tell, not much more. It's downloading the tar, extracting it correctly, but when it goes to move the updated module into place, it gives the same error, destination directory already exists. When I look at the directory, I see it is empty of files. There are other subdirectories. I've executed this command three times, and each time it leaves the module it's attempting to update broken.

Comment: Check how your PHP CLI is setup for to run. Sounds like a permissions issue.

Comment: @Brady - do you know what permissions I should look for? The really strange thing is that drush up works without an error on a Drupal 8 site.

Comment: In regards to the Homebrew question. I would use Composer for Drush. You are going to get the latest code with Composer, you will have to wait till the Homebrew package gets updated.  I love Homebrew but I do not use it for Drush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be hitting [this issue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1056) - there is a bug if you have a version control system such as SVN installed.

If it is this bug, the error should go away if you pass --version-control=backup.  Of course you will then lose some integration with your version control system.

Comment: It's weird that I'm getting a completely different error message. Thanks!